# Regex to get information from an input form

Tags: php, regex

I want to be able to catch the website url from this input form:

```
<input name="website" id="website" type="text" data-attr="website" value="https://www.toureiffel.paris/" placeholder="Entrer l’adresse URL du site Web">
```

This is what I used in my `preg_match`:

```
$page = file_get_contents('https://...');
preg_match('/data-attr=\"website\" value=\"(.+?)\"/is', $page, $website);
$website = $website[1];
```

But the `$website` variable is empty.

What I'm missing here please ?

Thanks.

Comment: Is there a line break between `"website"` and `value=` in the input?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, no I put one just to be more readable. I have updated it.

Comment: What if they change the way they assign attributes to an input element? Or is the site under your control?

Comment: It's a one shot code. I'm just testing things around.

Comment: Well, then the shown HTML source is not what you actually have. Not reproducible.

Comment: you should provide the correct link that you are loading.

Comment: Please provide to link to reproduce!

Answer (score -1):

sorry, but I guess you have an issue with the website loading instead of regex. Your example works perfectly fine:

```
<?php

$page = '<input name="website" id="website" type="text" data-attr="website" value="https://www.toureiffel.paris/" placeholder="Entrer l’adresse URL du site Web">';

preg_match('/data-attr=\"website\" value=\"(.+?)\"/is', $page, $website);
$website = $website[1];

print($website);

?>
```

does output:

```
https://www.toureiffel.paris/
```

the means the problem is within the line of

```
$page = file_get_contents('https://...');
```

so please provide correct link for reproducing.

Comment: it is to show that regex is fine. problem is about his website loading incorrectly!